# Windows Phone missing many methods in TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I can't find a way to call the function

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT");
```

from my Windows 8 Phone code. When I call this function from a normal Windows Forms Application it will find it, but when I try to use it from my app it says that is doesn't exists.

Comment: OK, so it's not part of the Phone framework. There might be workarounds, but it would help if you showed what you need it for.

Comment: I want to convert time to local New York time, because I want to make "global clock" application which will have many cities